# Access element from external XML file in Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android Application.I have create an another XML file for layout:-

**Chatfile.XML**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/suitableblack"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/signout"
    android:layout_width="422dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/Msgdisplay"
    android:layout_width="374dp"
    android:layout_height="593dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/signout"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:forceDarkAllowed="false" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="390dp"
    android:layout_height="83dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/Msgdisplay"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Msginput"
        android:layout_width="482dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Sendbtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So I want to access the button with ID-Sendbtn in  my MainActivity.java file and the code for that part is here:-

```
    Button sendbtn=findViewById(R.id.Sendbtn);
    sendbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          String msg=message.getText().toString();
          if(msg.length()==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Blank message detected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        else
        {
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().setValue(new chatcolumns(msg,FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName()));
        }

    }
  });
```

But whenever I run this code it gives me following error:-

```
 Process: com.example.anochatzone, PID: 18398
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.anochatzone/com.example.anochatzone.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.anochatzone.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:87)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

My main question is how can I access the button from chatfile.xml in my MainActivity.java

**Update**
MainActivity.java

```
  package com.example.anochatzone;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.Layout;    
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.*;

    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

    import java.util.Objects;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth authenticate;
        private String email_str="";
     private String password_str="";
    private EditText email,password,message;
    private Button loginbtn,resetbtn,sendbtn;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //will hide the title
            Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide(); // hide the title bar
            this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //enable full screen
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           email=findViewById(R.id.EmailInput);
           password=findViewById(R.id.Passwordinput);
           message=findViewById(R.id.Msginput);

    loginbtn=findViewById(R.id.Loginbtn);
           resetbtn= findViewById(R.id.ResetBtn);
       sendbtn=findViewById(R.id.Sendbtn);


        authenticate=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


       loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please wait while we are processing your request........",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                email_str=email.getText().toString();
                password_str=password.getText().toString();
            if(email_str.length()==0||password_str.length()==0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Please check email and password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                authenticate.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email_str,password_str).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                       if(task.isSuccessful()){
    Log.d("User display name" , FirebaseAuth . getInstance() . getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Welcome "+email_str+" you have sucessfully logged in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         setContentView(R.layout.chatfile);

                       }
                       else
                       {
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed to sign in .Please check internet connection or try again later",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }


                    }
                });
            }
           }
       });


    sendbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String msg=message.getText().toString();
        if(msg.length()==0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Blank message detected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        else
        {
             FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().setValue(new        chatcolumns(msg,FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName()))    ;
        }
    }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me the full code of MainActivity.java?

Comment: Can you show me the full code of your MainActivity.java? I think your are not using correct layout in  setContentView(R.layout.Chatfile)  .

Comment: OK i will add it

Comment: What is it that you are exactly looking for? Since the XML Layout `chatfile.xml` is a different XML Layout file, you won't be able to access the objects in your `MainActivity`, until and unless you either inflate it using `LayoutInflater` or by including it in your `activity_main.xml`. Also, if you just want a reference to a button, you can add the button to `MainActivity` too and use the click listener the way you are using in the `ChatActivity`. If you think I am missing something, please elaborate a bit more to help us better understand your requirements.

Comment: But after login all the elements of login page must be removed but inflater will add those elements to that file

Comment: After sucessful sign in the chatfile is in the setContentView()

Comment: @vedantGandhi I think you cannot bind layout like this. I want you to advice to separate two activity or you can use `View.VISIBLE` or `View.GONE` or `View.INVISIBLE` to show or hide your ui elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your purpose, when you launch or start the app, login page will appear. If login success, the chat page will appear.

So, you need to separate your activity to two activity such as `LoginActivity` as a launcher activity and `ChatActivity`(MainActivity) as follow.

For login page, may be one `activity_login.xml` and `LoginActivity.java`

In `activity_login.xml`

```
   <!-- You need one button for login action. -->
   <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Login"
      />
```

In `LoginActivity.java`

```
@Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // This line is important to access your resource id
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    findViewById(R.id.btnLogin).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        // isLoginSuccess is an example condition for you
        if (isLoginSuccess) {
          // Navigate to mainpage
          startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

          // Terminate the login activity for one time show.
          finish();
        } else {
          // TODO: Try again implementations
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

For main page, like above, you need one `activity_main.xml` and one `MainActivity.java`

In `Chatfile.xml`

```
      // other codes....
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/Sendbtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
      // other codes....
```

In `MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // This line is important for your 'chatfile.xml'
    setContentView(R.layout.Chatfile);

    // You can access id `SendBtn` right now.
    findViewById(R.id.SendBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override public void onClick(View v) {
          // TODO: implement something here.
      }
    });
  }
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, you need to change launcher activity as `LoginActivity`.

```
<application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"/>
  </application>
```

According to my solution, you don't have to consider that what the ui element should be hidden when login success or fail.

If anything wrong in my answer, please let me free to know.

Comment: Thank you so much,My error has been solved now and my application is functioning according to my needs.It has solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in your activity_main.xml

```
<include
    layout="@layout/chatfile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Now you can access the button in Your MainActivity.

Comment: After adding this code the elements from chatfile.xml are also being displayed on the start screen.I am displaying the chatfile.xml after login of the user .